# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in SSIS Script Task. Any solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, batch-processing

I am trying to attach all the txt files from a directory in email attachment in SSIS Script Task. I have the following code.

```
  String[] File1 = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Output\\", "*.txt");
   foreach (var File in File1)
   {
     Attachment Attach = new Attachment(File);
     email.Attachments.Add(Attach);
     FileNames = Path.GetFileName(File);     
    }
```

My Script Task is executing properly. The next step is Batch File Processing. The Batch File will copy the files in the output folder into SFTP and then move the files into archive folder. While executing the Batch File Task (i.e., Execute Process Task in SSIS). I am getting the below error.

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

When i run the Script Task and Execute Process Task individually , both the tasks is running properly. Email is triggered and the files is moved. But when i execute as SQL Job. I am getting the above error. I understood that the Script Task is holding the files. I even tried the following code in the foreach loop.

```
Attach.Dispose()
```

But when i add the above code, my SQL Job ran successfully but email is not triggered.

Comment: Have you tried with using for Attach?

Comment: I have tried as like below.

     using(Attachment Attach = new Attachment(File))
     {
       email.Attachments.Add(Attach);
       FileNames = Path.GetFileName(File); 
     }

I Modified the Script Task and then ran the SQL Job. The Job executed without errors, But the email is not triggered.

Comment: Where is client.Send(email) line? Can you show your code to send email please?

Comment: SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("SMTPServer");
                mySmtpClient.Send(email);
HardCoded the SMPT Server Name . For security reasons i have mentioned as SMPTServer.

Comment: according to your comment, have you checked db server has access to smtp server? smtp port? if attachments have the allowed size ?

Comment: My email Task runs without any errors with the given smtp server and there is no access issues. The issue is , the output file from data flow task will be created in a folder. The email task will attach the file from the output folder and will sends the email. Data flow Task and Email Task is running without any issues. The third Task is Batch File Task which will copy the output file into SFTP . In this Task only, the error is getting as "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.".